# Проверка строки с датой/временем на корректность в Ruby

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Нужно в Ruby проверить строку вида `'12.01.2016 14:26'`, корректные ли в ней дата/время.

Предполагаю, что это проще всего сделать при помощи *регулярного выражения*.

- Если регулярным выражением, то **каким**?
- Если **не** регулярным выражением, то **как** тогда?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Некоторые люди, столкнувшись с проблемой, думают: "Точно, я воспользуюсь регулярными выражениями". Теперь у них две проблемы.
>   — *Джейми Завински*

**Вам не нужны регулярные выражения для решения этой задачи.**

Решение есть в стандартной библиотеке Ruby. Это [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), принимающий строку и разбирающий её по [`strftime`-подобной маске](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime):

```
DateTime.strptime('12.01.2016 14:26', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
# => #<DateTime: 2016-01-12T14:26:00+00:00 ((2457400j,51960s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

В случае некорректности даты/времени прилетит исключение `ArgumentError`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d\d\d)\s+(\d\d)\:(\d\d)
```

Это ровно ваш пример

Comment: Он ошибочно воспримет "нулевое нулября" как корректную дату.